# Setting start position of CAKeyframeAnimation that follows an elliptical path

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview, core-animation, cakeyframeanimation

I am trying to animate a `UIView` in a circle using a `CAKeyframeAnimation` that follows a path created with `CGPathAddEllipseInRect`, which I have set up fine. Is there a way, however, to set the start position of the animation? My code is:

```
//set up animation
CAKeyframeAnimation *pathAnimation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
pathAnimation.calculationMode = kCAAnimationPaced;
pathAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
pathAnimation.removedOnCompletion = NO;
pathAnimation.duration = 10.0;
pathAnimation.repeatCount = 1000;
CGMutablePathRef curvedPath = CGPathCreateMutable();

//path as a circle
CGRect bounds = CGRectMake(60,170,200,200);
CGPathAddEllipseInRect(curvedPath, NULL, bounds);

//tell animation to use this path
pathAnimation.path = curvedPath;
CGPathRelease(curvedPath);

//add subview
circleView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ball.png"]];    
[testView addSubview:circleView];

//animate
[circleView.layer addAnimation:pathAnimation forKey:@"moveTheSquare"];
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `CGPathAddArc` instead of `CGPathAddEllipseInRect`.  For example:

```
CGFloat radiansForHour(CGFloat hour)
{
    return 2 * M_PI * (hour - 3) / 12;
}

...
    CGPathAddArc(curvedPath, NULL, 160, 270, 100, radiansForHour(11), radiansForHour(12 + 11), NO);
```

Note that if you want it to move through 12 hours, the `endAngle` parameter must be 12 hours more than the `startAngle`.

Comment: thanks for this, but how do i set the starting position of the animation so that it starts in position 11:00 on a clock, rather than it being at 5:00 now. if you know what i mean. I know its something to do with degrees start and end but i cant seem to figure it out. Cheers

Comment: Edited to provide hours to radians conversion.